# python regexp how to change text between boundaries but not between a tags

Tags: python, regex

In my web application (django) I use something (in a loop) like this to automatically change special words with internal links:

```
value = re.sub(r'\b' + keyword.name +r'\b', unicode(internal_link), value, flags=re.UNICODE|re.IGNORECASE)
```

Is there a way not to change a word when it is already a link?

(e.g. in between `>` and `</a>` characters or something better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
reg = r'<//a{0}>|\b{0}\b'.format(keyword.name)

value = re.sub(reg,
               lambda match: match.group(1) if match.group(1) else unicode(internal_link),
               value,
               flags=....)
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting a `'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(128)` error at: `reg = r'<//a{0}>|\b{0}\b'.format(keyword.name)`. Any ideas?